# How to test a rest API that requires certificate (X.509 Client Certificate)?

Tags: api, rest, keytool

I'm working on testing REST APIs that require issuing a certificate generated by keytool and signed by the provider (in this case Mastercard).
I've already generated the certificate and got it signed by Mastercard and now I need to test the APIs.

my question is:
What REST API testing tool should I use and how to add the signed certificate to the API request?

Below you can find details about the certificate generation and signing process

Pre-requisite for Rest API (as found in API Document)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg8uq.png

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I use Postman, it is real convenient for testing API's https://www.postman.com/.

I have never tried to add a signed certificate to any of my requests, but it looks like it's possible to achieve https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/.